# Count inventory quantity

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count the quantity of item left in the inventory, but I don't know how to make it happen.

1. Items

```
ITEM_ID   ITEM_BARCODE   ITEM_NAME       ITEM_ROP
-------------------------------------------------
101       76164231       Marlboro 20     20
102       76164217       Marlboro B 20   10
103       9555192501305  Juicy Fruit     5
104       9300682016278  M & M Crispy    5
```

2. Stocks

```
STOCK_ID  ITEM_ID  STOCK_QUANTITY   STOCK_DATE   
----------------------------------------------
001       101      20               01-JUL-18
002       104      30               02-JUL-18
003       101      50               02-JUL-18
004       104      20               05-JUL-18
005       103      45               06-JUL-18
```

3. Sales

```
SALES_ID  ITEM_ID  SALES_QUANTITY   SALES_DATE   
----------------------------------------------
001       101      20               02-JUL-18
002       104      30               02-JUL-18
003       101      35               03-JUL-18
004       103      20               09-JUL-18
```

And there should be two result, the first one as shown below where it will produce item quantity left based from table Stocks and Sales. Table Stocks will keep the record of item quantity. Meanwhile, table Sales is where it will keep the record of quantity item that has been sold (STOCK_QUANTITY - SALES_QUANTITY).

```
ITEM_BARCODE   ITEM_NAME         QUANTITY
------------------------------------------
76164231       Marlboro 20       15
76164217       Marlboro B 20     0
9555192501305  Juicy Fruit       25
9300682016278  M & M Crispy      20
```

The second output is where it will display based on which item is lower than the reorder point (ROP) as in table Items

```
ITEM_BARCODE   ITEM_NAME         QUANTITY  ROP
----------------------------------------------
76164231       Marlboro 20       15        20
76164217       Marlboro B 20     0         10
```

```
SELECT T.STOCK_DATE, 
       I.ITEM_BARCODE, 
       I.ITEM_NAME, 
       SUM(T.STOCK_QUANTITY) - SUM(S.SALES_QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY 
  FROM ITEMS I 
 INNER
  JOIN STOCKS T 
    ON I.ITEM_ID = T.ITEM_ID 
  LEFT 
  JOIN SALES S 
    ON I.ITEM_ID = S.ITEM_ID 
 GROUP 
    BY I.ITEM_BARCODE, 
       T.STOCK_DATE, 
       I.ITEM_NAME 
 ORDER 
    BY T.STOCK_DATE;
```

Anyone could help me with this? Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know how to use JOIN and GROUP BY?

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Forbs I guess not... he's a student trying to get us do his homework... SO is full of them.

Comment: You've done a lot right with this question - Posting the well formatted sample data, posting the expected results, tagged DBMS, etc... But since this does look a lot like homework you should also post your best attempt at the query so far. Hint: Your looking for a difference in sums aggregating by item.

Comment: @Forbs I know how to use JOIN and GROUP BY but since I need to get the item quantity left by deducting stock quantity and sales quantity by date, I wonder how to perform the sql by different date.

Comment: @olleo yes, I think he is trying to get us to do his homework, that's why I said JOIN and GROUP BY, he can then look up an answer for it.  Well if he is in school, he probably already knew that he needed those two commands

Comment: @NadhirahAziz show us your current code and maybe we can help you adjust it.

Comment: Do you have to look up by each date or is it just a total of end-of-period quantities? What level of class is this for? And again, is this MySQL 5x or 8x? The answers could be different.

Comment: How am i supposed to know whether it is version 5 or 8?

Comment: SELECT  T.STOCK_DATE, I.ITEM_BARCODE, I.ITEM_NAME, SUM(T.STOCK_QUANTITY)-SUM(S.SALES_QUANTITY) AS QUANTITY
FROM ITEMS I
JOIN STOCKS T
ON I.ITEM_ID = T.ITEM_ID
LEFT JOIN SALES S
ON I.ITEM_ID = S.ITEM_ID
GROUP BY I.ITEM_BARCODE, T.STOCK_DATE, I.ITEM_NAME
ORDER BY T.STOCK_DATE;

Comment: Run this query: `select version() `. Then your SQL statement above, as well as your MySQL version, should be added to your question and not posted in the comments. Come on you will do it. That's what learning is about

Comment: @Forbs So he does'nt even now how to find the version he's using... I mean being a student does not prevent him to do a quick search. I am so fed up of SO with those like him and those who ask but does not mark the question answered. That's why screen those guys right away like the OP

Comment: @Error_2646 Sooooooo true ! +1

Comment: @olleo I don't mind student questions as long as the requisite work has been put in. I'm not about to do code-it-for-me on homework though. Personally I think being able to ask good technical questions on online forums is a valuable technical skill and it's just as well that they develop it in school.

Comment: The query you've tried is very close. Some things to consider: Why are you grouping by stock_date, does this really need to be part of your aggregation? An item will only have 1 reorder point, so you can add this to your group by and select cause without any collateral damage.

Comment: I am sorry because I didn’t know the version of it and even didn’t try to find it by myself. I’m still new at this. Before posting this question, I’ve try to look a solution that are similar to my problem, but those query are too long for me to understand. By posting this question, I just hope that someone who have more knowledge into this could help and guide me.

Comment: @Error_2646 I’ve removed the date. And it seems work for me. Thank you.

Comment: @nadhirahaziz Good work. Don't hesitate to ask questions here. Asking good questions on online forums is a skill and it's fine to learn it in school. Just remember to (As you did) put sample data, expected result, and the code from your best try along with what is tripping you up. I know it seems like people were rude initially. A lot of people answering question on here get paid to do this type of work so they might get a bit prickly when they think they're getting homework pawned off on them.  Again, good work, I'm glad you were able to work out the solution.